# Calling a method which returns Resultset

Tags: java, jsp, exception, jdbc, resultset

I am building a `3-tier` application which uses `java` classes for retrieving data from `db` and `jsp` pages for the user interface. When I try to call a method in a jsp page which returns resultset, I get this error message:

> Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed.

For example, I have this method:

```
public ResultSet getName(String country) throws SQLException {
    String name;
    try {
        open();
        stmt1 = con.prepareStatement(fetchPanepistimio);
        stmt1.setString(1,country);
        rs1 = stmt1.executeQuery();
        stmt1.close();
        close();
    }catch(Exception e2) {
    }

    return rs1;

}
```

and when I write in a jsp page the following:

```
<%

ResultSet rs = panepistimio.getName(country);

while(rs.next()) { %>

...........
<% } %>
```

I get the exception which I described. Have you got any idea about what is going wrong? Thank you in advance

Comment: What you exactly want to return, the ResultSet or the Query result?

Comment: the contents of the data base. In this case, I want the names of the universities which are on the database

Comment: Then you first get the content from ResultSet then return it in String, but you close the ResultSet then return, it definitely not working.

Comment: This is cause because you close(); before getting resultset

Comment: @BahramdunAdil I wil try it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access the ResultSet after closing the database connection `stmt1.close();` and `close();`), which doesn't work that way. (see [Oracle's tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) for a longer explanation).

Instead of leaving the connection open, you should retrieve the content of the `ResultSet` and then use it in your JSP page.
That way, you decouple the life cycle of the DB query from your view life cycle.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the `ResultSet` is closed when you call `stmt1.close()`. Perform your database access within the single method, add the results to an appropriate `Collection` and return it.

For example:

```
public Collection<String> getName(String country) {
    String sql = "...";
    Collection<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    try(Statement statement = ...; ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql)){
        while(resultSet.next()) {
            names.add(resultSet.getString(...));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // LOG
    }
    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're closing the `PreparedStatement` object that created the `ResultSet` immediately after executing the query (and potentially also closing the `Connection`).

From the documentation for the [`Statement#close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) method (`PreparedStatement` is a child of `Statement`):

> Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up database resources.
>
> Calling the method close on a Statement object that is already closed has no effect.
>
> Note:**When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.**

Emphasis mine.

Ideally you should materialise the contents of your `ResultSet` into a formal collection and send that collection to the JSP instead of the `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You call close on the statement, which you should not.

Second, you should not swallow exeptions as in `catch(Exception e2) {}`.
This makes it hard or impossible to trace errors.

Third, it is not good practise to iterate over a `ResultSet` in a JSP. This should be done in the backend e.g. (in `getName`). see [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)